# "device is not defined" on my ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I know this is asking many times but i cannot find a solution. I have a ionic app and i want to get the device UUID. Here are my codes:
Here is my index.html;

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.10.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap-sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
```

My controller;

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaDevice) {

$scope.uuid = "";
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
    $scope.uuid = $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
  } else {
    console.log('It is not an android');
  };

});
```

})

When i run the code console is give me

> Uncaught ReferenceError: device is not defined

I import ngCordova to app.js module too. I did everything right but still i cannot handle it. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: what about angular-uuid module to generate your uuid inject to your controller ?

Comment: Is it change everytime when reinstall the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was based on the .js files which listed in index.html. I don't know why but when I import `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` to index.html it is ok. But when call cordova.js from another file for example `<script src="js/cordova.js"></script>`, it does not work. So, I changed my index.html like;

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.10.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap-sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
```

And it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your import order of your script on top of your index page.

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

Please also check if you have installed the cordovaDevice plugin using the command?

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

Comment: No. when i do that i got `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined` error. Thanks anyway.